# NullpointException when reading file with RowCsvInputFormat in flink

Tags: scala, file, streaming, apache-flink, kryo

I am a beginner on Flink streaming.

When reading a file with RowCsvInputFormat, the code that Kryo serializer creates Row does not work properly.

The code is below.

```
    val readLocalCsvFile = new RowCsvInputFormat(
      new Path("flink-test/000000_1"),
      Array(Types.STRING, Types.STRING, Types.STRING),
      "\n",
      ","
    )

    val read = env.readFile(
      readLocalCsvFile,
  "flink-test/000000_1",
      FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY,
      1000000)

    read.print()
    env.execute("test")
```

The contents of the file 000000_1 are as follows.

aa,bb,cc

aaa,bbb,ccc

As a result of debugging, I get the divided values ​​of aa, bb, and cc well. But when I put those values ​​into Row's fields one by one, a nullpointexception is raised because fields are null.

The image below shows that the fields of the Row are null.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5BQb.png)

The code that creates a Row when the above code is executed is as follows. KryoSerializer generates the row.

```
    val kryo = new EmptyFlinkScalaKryoInstantiator().newKryo
    val Row = kryo.newInstance(classOf[Row])
```

The output error is as follows.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.flink.types.Row.setField(Row.java:140)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.RowCsvInputFormat.fillRecord(RowCsvInputFormat.java:162)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.RowCsvInputFormat.fillRecord(RowCsvInputFormat.java:33)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.CsvInputFormat.readRecord(CsvInputFormat.java:113)
at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.DelimitedInputFormat.nextRecord(DelimitedInputFormat.java:551)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.CsvInputFormat.nextRecord(CsvInputFormat.java:80)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.ContinuousFileReaderOperator.readAndCollectRecord(ContinuousFileReaderOperator.java:387)
at
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can post the complete code.

Judging from the task error report, it may be because the number of fields does not match

Comment: Hello. First of all, thank you for your interest in the question.
The question has been edited to be more detailed.